# Display timeline in HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this table, which shows the current status of the request. A sample table will look as below in HTML

[image]

Table is pretty simple, only issue is how to display that timeline in the status. I won't mind using some grid for same purpose if it shows timeline as below or something similar.

Timeline in New Approved In Progress etc.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `:before` and `:after` for continuous timeline.

We will have two classes for that: `.has-left` and `.has-right` to define timeline display:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.timeline {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline span {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: none;
}
.timeline.has-left:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  top: 12px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.timeline.has-right:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  top: 12px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.timeline.has-left span,
.timeline.has-right span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td class="timeline has-right"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline has-left has-right"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline has-left"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline"><span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="timeline has-right"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline has-left"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline has-right"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline has-left"><span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="timeline"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline has-right"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline has-left has-right"><span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="timeline has-left"><span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: WOW Justinas, exactly same thing I was looking for. Perfect and thanks.

Comment: Is there a chance of showing only symbol without left and right line?

Comment: @user2739418 Yes, just change default display of `.timeline span` to `display: inline-block` and remove `.timeline.has-left span, .timeline.has-right span` rule.

Answer (score 0):

My approach (if forced into using tables) would be to apply some CSS `:after` selectors.

HTML

```
<table width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <th width="25%">Item</th>
  <th width="25%">Status 1</th>
  <th width="25%">Status 2</th>
  <th width="25%">Status 3</th>
</tr>
<tr class="status3">
  <td>Stat3</td>
  <td><i class="circle"></i></td>
  <td><i class="circle"></i></td>
  <td><i class="circle"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr class="status1">
  <td>Stat1</td>
  <td><i class="circle"></i></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="status2">
  <td>Stat2</td>
  <td><i class="circle"></i></td>
  <td><i class="circle"></i></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
i.circle {display:block;width:20px;height:20px;border-radius:10px;background:#ccc;margin:auto}
tr.status3 td:nth-child(2):after,
tr.status3 td:nth-child(3):after,
tr.status3 td:nth-child(4):after,
tr.status2 td:nth-child(2):after,
tr.status2 td:nth-child(3):after {    
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 5px;
    content: ' ';
    float: right;
    margin-top: -12px;
}
tr.status3 td:nth-child(3):after{
    width: 100%;
}
tr.status3 td:nth-child(4):after{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
tr.status2 td:nth-child(3):after{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

See the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lz3zfLn/

Comment: @Paulie_D - I was stubbing out the answer first.

Comment: No need to be the fastest gun. You should always post complete answers...not placeholders. We don't KNOW you're going to complete the answer later.

Comment: This is what i was expecting and this is what I have achieved. https://jsfiddle.net/5737a0x9/